# how to change border color of JProgressBar

Tags: java

I want to change the color of the border of JProgressBar, I have used JProgressBar.setBorder(Color.CYAN); but this not working. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

That's not how to setBorders. You need to use a BorderFactory.

```
JProgressBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.CYAN));
```

check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html